# CKEDITOR - Problemas com formatação vinda do WORD

Tags: ckeditor

se eu pegar um texto formatado do word e colar no ckeditor ele vem cheio de css, spam, brs, etc...

No editor do Wordpress isso não acontece, ele deixa tudo limpo, mas mantém os parágrafos, strongs, listas. Tem como deixar ele da mesma forma?

Se não houver tem alguma alternativa free ao ckeditor?

Comment: O CKEditor tem um ícone onde vc pode colar texto sem formatação.

Comment: @dvd não funciona.

Comment: Se quiser testar uso essa cdn <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.9.2/full/ckeditor.js"></script> dá uma olhada só.

Comment: @dvd deve ter algum parametro que faz esse lixo de styles sumirem ao colar, assim como faz o editor do wrodpress. Se vc pegar qualquer texto e jogar no wordpress só fica os strong e paragráfos. No bloguer vem um monte de lixo, no ckeditor também.